# PHP Doctrine2 persisted Entity vs new Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've looking all over the web, and it looks like I'm the only one that's annoyed/frustrated by this...
Let me explain.

I'm using Doctrine2 to build a series of entities
Something like this
(leaving out all the Doctrine annotations, getters & setters):

```
<?php

class Article
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $categories = [];
}

class Category
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $articles = [];
}

// create some categories
$cat1 = new Category();
$cat1->setName('cat-01');

$cat2 = new Category();
$cat2->setName('cat-02');

$cat3 = new Category();
$cat3->setName('cat-03');

// new Article
$article = new Article();
$article->setName('foo');
$article->setCategories([$cat1, $cat2, $cat3]);
```

Now, if you need to filter the Article's categories, you have to use array_filter();

```
$cats = array_filter($article->getCategories(), function($cat) {
    return $cat->getName() === 'cat-01';
});
```

Right.... that makes sense.

BUT, once the Article object is persisted and recovered from DB, you can use the PersistentCollection::filter(Closure $c) method
array_filter won't work though

```
$entityManager->persist($article);
$entityManager->flush();


$article = $entityManager->getRepository('Article')->findById(1);
$cats = $article->getCategories()->filter(function($cat) {
    return $cat->getName() === 'cat-01';
});
```

Same thing with array_map() vs PersistentCollection::map()
or current() vs PersistentCollection::current()
etc. etc. etc.

Now...
The question is, is there a way for my non persisted Entity to work the same way as a persisted one?
Or is there a way to make this work on persisted AND non persisted entities ?

```
$cats = $article->getCategories()->filter(function($cat) {
    return $cat->getName() === 'cat-01';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a native array, try using doctrine's [`ArrayCollection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html), which is probably the same type that your persisted entity is using:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Article
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $categories;

    function __construct() {
       $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }        
}

class Category
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $articles;

    function __construct() {
       $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }        
}
```

The following should now work on non-persisted entities:

```
// create some categories
$cat1 = new Category();
$cat1->setName('cat-01');

$cat2 = new Category();
$cat2->setName('cat-02');

$cat3 = new Category();
$cat3->setName('cat-03');

// new Article
$article = new Article();
$article->setName('foo');
$article->setCategories([$cat1, $cat2, $cat3]);

$cats = $article->getCategories()->filter(function($cat) {
    return $cat->getName() === 'cat-01';
});
```

You did not show the code but I'm guessing the problem lies with your Articles::setCategories method.  I suspect you have

```
class Articles {
  public function setCategories(array categories) {
    $this->categories = $categories;
```

This causes your ArrayCollection to be overwritten by a regular php array.

Instead do something like:

```
class Articles {
  public function setCategories(array categories) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
      $this->categories[] = $category;
```

This will preserve the array collection and allow the filter function to work for new entities as well as retrieved ones.

Comment: I'm guessing that Doctrine2 will be able to handle an ArrayCollection for the OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany association?

Comment: and that it's good practice to initialize the ArrayCollections in the constructor?

Comment: @dGo yes, I generally initialize array collections in the constructor. you should be able to use this for any type of association

Comment: @FuzzyTree - Might want to update your answer with my setCategories method and then I'll delete mine.